# Is it ok to use useState hook setter to retrieve data, to avoid re-renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

### Short story

I want to know if this is ok to do:

```
  const onClick = useCallback(() => {
     setHoveredItem((hovered)=>{
       setSelectedData(hovered);
       return hovered;
     });
  },[]);
```

Just using the useState setter to get the value, 'removing' the useCallback's dependency to avoid re-renders. Notice the empty dependency array.
Is that an acceptable way to do things?

### Long story

I am working on an application with an chart. Re-renders to the chart are really bad (they basically break). So I used React.memo. All good until I needed to pass event listeners:

```
<MemoChart
    {...{ data, onHover, onClick }}>
</MemoChart>
```

On click, I want to store the hovered item.

Initially, this was my onClick function:

```
  const onClick = () => {
    setSelectedData(hoveredItem);
  }
```

But of course, every hover event re-renders the parent, which causes the chart to re-render. Use Callback on onClick would work, except that if I add a dependency on hoveredItem, it will do nothing.

So this is what I did. It works, but I have never seen it done and I wonder if it is ok to do:

```
  const onClick = useCallback(() => {
     setHoveredItem((hovered)=>{
       setSelectedData(hovered);
       return hovered;
     });
  },[]);
```

Comment: I think will be better: useEffect(()=>setSelectedData(hovered),[hovered]), rethink why do you need it in general, feels like duplicated state. if you want without rerender in react 17: setTimeout(()=>{
setState1()
setState2()
},0)

Comment: Seems the key here is `useCallback` for the functions you're passing in to the chart component. If you want to prevent state changes to the parent from re-rendering the child, those functions should be memoized.

Comment: Helpful: https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#automatic-batching

Comment: If you share a minimal reproducible example in a codesandbox then the community might be able to help you better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**

For your case, I think you can use `useRef` to keep hovered data instead of a state.

```
const hoveredRef = React.useRef()

const onHover = useCallback((hovered) => {
   hoveredRef.current = hovered //won't make re-rendering
}, [])

const onClick = useCallback(() => {
   setSelectedData(hoveredRef.current)
}, [])
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

```
<MemoChart
    {...{ data, onHover, onClick }}>
</MemoChart>
```

Your problem is these events `onHover` and `onClick` will be initialized newly every time which will cause unexpected renderings. If you have a complex computation on your component, it will be laggy on renderings.

In your `onClick` case with `useCallback`, it works but it will create more trouble in state handlers because it's lacking dependencies which means it's considering that function will be the same all the time, but in fact, your function is relying on `hovered` state should be changed on events.

I'd propose that you should pass dependencies to align with your used states in functions.

```
const onHover = useCallback((hovered) => {
   setHoveredItem(hovered);
}, []) //only initialize this function once after the component mounted

const onClick = useCallback(() => {
     setSelectedData(hovered);
},[hovered]); //initialize this function again when `hovered` state changes
```

Comment: Thanks. But setting hovered as a dependency *will* cause my chart to re-render when hovered changes. I know it's a better way, but in my case it doesn't avoid the re-render that I really cannot have.

Comment: Just one thing I want to know, `onHover` and `onClick` are on the same element? If that's the case, you don't need to have another state for `hovered` @RSinohara

Comment: They are not. The click is anywhere in the chart and should save the latest hovered data point (which might not be under the mouse anymore).

Answer (score 1):

```
const onClick = useCallback(() => {
     setHoveredItem((hovered)=>{
       setSelectedData(hovered);
       return hovered;
     });
  },[]);
```

This is not wrong, but it's a hack that helps you getting the fresh state if you have closures issues.
In your case there is no reason since you are not working with closures, and the problem is just that you set an empty deps array.
Now you say that this does not work:

```
const onClick = useCallback(() => {
       setSelectedData(hovered);
  },[hovered]);
```

But this **MUST** work, unless you are doing something wrong when you call `setHovereditem`.

Comment: Hey, thanks. But I cannot do that, the hovered dependency will cause onClick to change, and then the Chart to re-render

Comment: If the hovering does not need  to trigger a re-render, why not using a ref instead of setting the item at state then ?

Comment: When you hover the chart, I want to store which point was hovered. The chart doesn't change, so it doesn't need to re-render. So I need a way to not re-create the click handler.
Adding hovered to the dependency will cause the click handler to be re-created and the chart to re-render.

Comment: Then that's perfect scenario to store the hovering info in a ref and not in a state.

Comment: Nice. But I am still curious if my original way would be valid, if for some reason the hover change should cause re-renders (but still not on the chart)

Comment: It's one of the hacks you can use to read fresh state when you are stuck in stale state closures. In your case I would definitely use a ref, since it's the perfect scenario for the usage of a ref .